# bullets creation in a simple game

Tags: java

I am creating a simple game where shapes fall and the player shoots them, but I am having problems creating bullet at every click of the mouse. I have tried various logic with no help, so am just going to put the code up here so you guys can take a look at it and help me out.

The bullet I created is not been created on every click just one is created and it moves on every click which is wrong........I want one bullet to be created per click.

```
// My main class: mousework2

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class mousework2 extends JFrame
{
    public static int Width = 300;
    public static int Height = 400;
    private JPanel p1;
    private Image pixMage,gunMage;

    public mousework2()
    {
        super("shoot-em-up");

        this.setSize(Width, Height);
        this.setResizable(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Dimension pos = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int x = (pos.width - Width) / 2;
        int y = (pos.height - Height) / 2;

        this.setLocation(x, y);

        p1 = new CreateImage();
        this.add(p1);
        this.getContentPane();

        Thread t = new recMove(this);
        t.start();
    }

    class recMove extends Thread
    {
        JFrame b;

        public recMove(JFrame b)
        {
            this.b = b;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            while (true) {
                b.repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class CreateImage extends JPanel implements MouseListener
    {
        ArrayList<fallShape> rect = new ArrayList<fallShape>();
        int x_pos = mousework.Width / 2;
        int y_pos = mousework.Height - 50;
        int bx_pos = mousework.Width / 2;
        int by_pos = mousework.Height;
        int y_speed = -10;
        boolean clicked;

        public CreateImage()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                rect.add(new fallShape(15, 15, rect));
            }

            Toolkit picx = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            gunMage = picx.getImage("gunner.jpg");
            gunMage = gunMage.getScaledInstance(200, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

            Toolkit pic = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            pixMage = pic.getImage("ballfall3.jpg");
            pixMage = pixMage.getScaledInstance(200, -1, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

            addMouseListener(this);
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    x_pos = e.getX() - 5;
                }
            });
        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getButton() == 1) {
                clicked = true;
            }
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getButton() == 1) {
                clicked = false;
            }
        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
        {
        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
        {
        }

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paint(g);

            g.drawImage(pixMage, 0, 0, Width, Height, null);

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.drawImage(gunMage,x_pos,y_pos,10,20,null);

            if (clicked) {
                by_pos += y_speed;
                Shape bullet = new Rectangle2D.Float(bx_pos, by_pos, 3, 10);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.fill(bullet);
                g2.draw(bullet);
            }

            g2.setColor(Color.RED);

            for (fallShape b : rect) {
                b.move();
                g2.fill(b);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new mousework2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And:

```
// My falling shapes class: fallShape

import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.*;

public class fallShape extends Rectangle2D.Float
{
    public int x_speed, y_speed;
    public int l, b;
    public int height = mousework.Height;
    public int width = mousework.Width;
    public ArrayList<fallShape> fall;

    public fallShape(int breadth, int length, ArrayList<fallShape> fall)
    {
        super((int) (Math.random() * (mousework.Width - 20) + 1), 0, breadth, length);
        this.b = breadth;
        this.l = length;
        this.x_speed = (int) Math.random() * (10) + 1;
        this.y_speed = (int) Math.random() * (10) + 1;
        this.fall = fall;
    }

    public void move()
    {
        Rectangle2D rec = new Rectangle2D.Float(super.x, super.y, b, l);

        for (fallShape f : fall) {
            if (f != this && f.intersects(rec)) {
                int rxspeed = x_speed;
                int ryspeed = y_speed;
                x_speed = f.x_speed;
                y_speed = f.y_speed;
                f.x_speed = rxspeed;
                f.y_speed = ryspeed;
            }
        }

        if (super.x < 0) {
            super.x =+ super.x;
            //super.y =+ super.y;
            x_speed = Math.abs(x_speed);
        }

        if (super.x> mousework.Width - 30) {
            super.x =+ super.x;
            super.y =+ super.y;
            x_speed =- Math.abs(x_speed);
        }

        if (super.y < 0) {
            super.y = 0;
            y_speed = Math.abs(y_speed);
        }

        super.x += x_speed;
        super.y += y_speed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more information? What errors are you receiving, what have you tried, what specifically isn't working, etc? This makes it a lot easier to answer than just a code dump and "fix this".

Comment: ok the bullet I created is not been created on every click just one is created and it moves on every click which is wrong........I want one bullet to be created per click.

Comment: Unrelated to your main problem, but you are using `=+` and `=-` in some places in your `fallShape.move()` method (I assume you meant to use `+=` and `-=` instead).

Comment: I actually wanted it to be =+.......just wanted to make it positive and not add to increment by value

Comment: While `x = -x` will reverse the sign of `x`, `x = +x` does absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(clicked){
    by_pos+=y_speed;
```

This code only draws the bullet when the mouse is down. This is because you are setting `clicked` to `false` in your `mouseReleased` method:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    if(e.getButton()==1)
        clicked=false;
}
```

If you were to remove the body of the `mouseReleased` method, your bullet would move properly.

---

However, say you wanted to have more than just one bullet. Currently, your `paint` method only draws one bullet at a time. To draw multiple bullets, you would need to create a list of the coordinates of the bullets, and add a new coordinate pair to the list whenever you click. Then, in the `paint` method, just update each position in a `for` loop.

```
ArrayList<Integer> by_poss = new ArrayList<>();
```

`by_poss` is the list of all the y-positions of your bullets.

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    if(e.getButton() == 1)
        by_poss.add(mousework.Height);
}
```

The `mousePressed` method adds a new "bullet", in the form of a y-position, to the coordinates.

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    //do nothing
}
```

Nothing needs to happen in the `mouseReleased` method.

```
//update the bullets
public void paint(Graphics g){
    ...
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    Shape bullet;
    for(int i = 0; i < by_poss.size(); i++){
        by_poss.set(i, by_poss.get(i) + y_speed); //move the bullet
        bullet = new Rectangle2D.Float(bx_pos, by_poss.get(i), 3, 10);
        g2.fill(bullet);
        g2.draw(bullet);
    }
    ...
}
```

The `for` loop in your `paint` method draws all the bullets, one by one, usin g the y-positions from the `by_poss` list.

Comment: Thanks very much people that actually did the trick I mean this is amazing.....got a long way to go with game programming.Thanks much again.

Comment: Please frenchDolphin can you do a little explanation of the code so I can understand better....thanks much

Comment: Please frenchDolphin my bullet created do not remove the falling rectangles when they are rapidly clicked only the last bullet released does now I have to click and wait before for it to intersect a rectangle before clicking again I really don't want this I want it to work on every bullet to do it.....Please how do I go about that have tried my utmost best it's still  not working......Thanks in advance for your help